# Remove spaces before the first word in string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I know how to remove one or many spaces before the first word in a string in C, but I don't know in C++ (if there is a function by example).

My string is : "   Hello" and I want to get "Hello". How can I do ?

Comment: How about `boost::trim_left` thats c++

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::string::find_first_not_of(' ')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to get the index of the first non-whitespace character, then take the substring from there

Example:

```
std::string str = " Hello";
auto pos = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
auto Trimmed = str.substr(pos != std::string::npos ? pos : 0);
```

---

```
std::string TrimLeft(const std::string& str){
    auto pos = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
    return str.substr(pos != std::string::npos ? pos : 0);
}
```